# How to reset the placeholder to the original value after modifying it with jquery

Tags: jquery, placeholder

I have a checkbox and some input fields for placing a bill(first name,second name,details etc).

Some of this informations can be tooked from account, so if the user check the checkbox, they will have to deal with only two input fields and the rest of them will be disabled.

The problem is that, every input field have different placeholders like this:

- First name-> "Insert your first name"
- Second name-> "Insert you second name"  etc

When the user will press the checkbox, some input fields will be disabled and the placeholder will go from the original text(ex:"insert your first name") to "The bill will be made with the details from account".

If the user check and the uncheck the checkbox, the placeholders will be available, but the placeholder will still be The bill will be made with the details from account".

How can i reset the palceholders to the original value?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
if ($('input[name="checkboxField"]:checked').length > 0){
    $("#inputField").attr("placeholder", "The bill will be made with the details from account");
}else{
    $("#inputField").attr("placeholder", "Insert your first name");
}
```

Comment: I can't beacuse i have a specific placeholder for each input fields